# Error when trying to export from xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode

Thirty minutes ago I exported my application to take the ipa file.
Now after some changes I made to my code I tried to export it again but now I have this error:

> An error occured during export  Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21

I changed build and version numbers but nothing.

I tried an older version again and it worked. 
What I can possible changed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Go to your projects **Build Phases** > **Copy Bundle Resources** and if you see any `.bundle` file delete it!
Then run again all the process and will work. At least it worked for me this way!

Comment: I just tried it and it worked but the bundle I unistalled now crash the tab that it used it...:/

Answer (score 0):

As the bundle that caused the problem was important in my project I tried to use my changes in a back up I had. I did all with copy paste from the latest project and now all works fine! The export is finally be done!

Kwnstantinos Natsios thank you for your answer you saved my day with this quick solution